# trying to store array values for an 'undo' function in p5js

Tags: javascript, arrays, processing, p5.js, undo

I've made a sort of drawing application in p5js - I have a multidimensional array called `points` which consists of shapes, which have x,y coordinates for the points of shapes. So:

```
shapes[0][0] = [10,10]
shapes[1][3] = [47,98]
```

etc.

I have a mousePressed function. At the time the mouse is pressed, before the points of these shapes are manipulated, I want to store the original shapes array as `undoArr`.

Then, as the user drags the mouse, the coordinates in the shapes array are updated. If the user then decides to undo, I have a function `keyPressed` that I want to be able to populate `shapes` array with the values from `undoArr`.

But no matter what I try - it seems that the undo array and the shapes array always have the same values, which is strange because, if I log the state of a coordinate in the shapes array:

```
function mousePressed() {
  if (!isMousePressed){
    undoArr = [...shapes]; //define undoArr as the current shapes array
    console.log(shapes[0][0]); //outputs 10,41 (for example)
```

and then log the state on `mouseReleased`:

```
function handleMouseReleased(){
    console.log(shapes[0][0]); //outputs 69,122 (for example)
```

I can verify that they have different values at start and finish. And I can verify from the logs that mousePressed is not accidentally being triggered somehow when it shouldn't, and the same for mouseReleased.

P5js has a draw function, which is constantly repositioning the points of the `shapes` array based on where the user drags them with their mouse. And in that draw function, I can place a log statement and verify that it fires after `mousePressed` and before `mouseReleased`.

However, if I try to store the values of the shapes array on mousePressed, `undoArr = [...shapes]` and then on keyPressed try to populate the `shapes` array with the contents of the `undoArr`, it does nothing - because somehow `undoArr` always contains the same data as `shapes`.

Am I copying the array improperly? I've tried instead of the spread `undoArr = shapes.slice()` but that also didn't work. I've even tried emptying the array first, but nothing seems to work.

A [complete gist of the file is available here.](https://gist.github.com/heaversm/5412de6169cc890c074a531a50d6828c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need here is a deep clone of your multidimensional array. It seems like you are just copying references instead of values.

The spread operator ([...]) does not do a deep clone, so the objects it copies will contain references.

Lodash has a great cloneDeep function: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#cloneDeep

or you could write one of your own.

Comment: Yes! I just realized that. Wow, been programming a long time and never realized that the nested values in an array would still be references to the original. (This SO post tipped me off: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copy-array-by-value). I wrote my own function, but it's nice to know about lodash. Thanks.

Comment: happy to help!!